# wordpress different header image per page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've done a custom theme now the client want to be able to upload a different header image for each page within the backend of WP. Does a plugin exist for this or what custom coding would I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search plugins: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Re: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-headers/